# Mounting CD drive

Tags: mount, cd-drive

I'm attempting to mount my CD drive so that I can use it,  and I'm confused on all the necessary steps I need to take to get it working smoothly. When I go to my disk utilities it is popping up on my screen and I can eject the disc by clicking eject on the screen, but it says there is no medium in drive when there is.  What method should I take to start? And can someone explain exactly what mounting completely entails, thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to select optical drives with media in them in Nautilus, in which case they're mounted as soon as you click on the drive symbol. Does that not work on your system?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nautilus at all I'm quite new to ubuntu Unix based in grneral, do I need to install that package?

Comment: [Nautilus](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus/) is the the default file manager of Ubuntu. Unless you removed it, you should already have and have used it.

Answer (score 16):

Usually, if a CD or DVD is inserted, you can see them under `/dev/cdrom`. You wont be able to view the contents from that location directly such as by doing `cd /dev/cdrom` or ls .

You can mount this CD by creating a mount point or using the existing mount point such as **/media**

**run the following command**

```
 sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media
 #you can use your custom mount point as well if this is on your desktop or somewhere else
```

For more information on the mount command, You can read the manual pages by doing `man mount`

That's it. You should be able to see the files under  /media folder now.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

Add your original ubuntu_server.iso file in your VM CD drive from manual setting option and then check how many media available with you

```
#sudo ls /media/
cdrom floppy1 floppy2
```

Then is not there then create a directory

```
#cd /media
#sudo mkdir cdrom
#ls
cdrom floppy1 floppy2
@[this CDROM have been created with this command
```

after then mount this cdrom in your DEV directory

```
#cd
[then go to home/main directory for mount]
```

run bellow commant and boom! mount your CDROM on ubuntu_server

```
#sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
[this will mount your CDROM on ubuntu server successfully]
```

Thanks!!!