# unrecognized service when starting ssh

Tags: server, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a remote Ubuntu computer at work via SSH from my laptop running Ubuntu.

At first, I just tried running:

```
$ ssh work_name@work_machine
```

But nothing happened.

Searching for a tutorial on the net, I followed [the instructions on this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu)

I suppose I need to activate the possibility for such a connection, so I typed in the terminal on my laptop

```
sudo service ssh start
```

After typing my password, I received the following message:

```
ssh: unrecognized service.
```

I wish someone could help me understand what should be done for the SSH remote connection to work.

Comment: The ssh service is for running an ssh server; you don't need that on your laptop if you're only using it as a client. Are you able to `ping -c 1 work_machine` successfully from your laptop? Does your work computer have an SSH server installed and configured? Are you able to ssh into your work computer from other machines?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the ping. My work computer now has an SSH server installed. What should be configured, and how?

Comment: I'm afraid that SSH server configuration and setting up port forwarding can be a bit complex if you're completely new to networking and the command line; there are plenty of guides online that can explain it much better than I can. You might want to look into a more user-friendly method of connecting to your work computer, such as Teamviewer or Chrome Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've already configured port forwarding and are able to get through to the machine at work.

Otherwise, even after following my answer, you won't get very far.

---

The SSH *server* is not installed by default.

You will need to install it by running these commands in a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) on the machine you wish to connect **to**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then you will be able to connect normally by running:

```
#Replace user & IP accordingly
ssh user@192.168.3.321
```

---

**However, in that state you have a security risk.**

As Oli has noted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/51926/518562),

> You **need** to harden it from the standard setup. [I've gone through
>   several suggestions on my blog](https://askubuntu.com/a/51926/518562) but at the very least, I'd suggest:
>
> - Key-based logins. Disable password logins.
> - Move it off port 22. Use something crazy-high, in the 20000-60000 range.
> - Use `fail2ban` to ban people who do find it and try to brute it.
>
> They take about 10 minutes in total and you go from a 1/10000 chance
>   of being broken in to a probability so small, there isn't enough paper
>   in the world to write its fraction... Assuming you're careful with
>   your key, it has a password of its own and you don't trumpet your
>   credentials all over the net.
>
> If the computer is behind a router, you'll also want to do some port
>   forwarding. This is router-specific so I'll just direct you to
>   http://portforward.com

Comment: I managed to follow all these instructions until reaching the step of copying the ssh-id after using key-gen. After typing 'ssh-copy-id -p <port_number> work_name@work_device' again nothing happens.

Comment: @MeirZeilig-Hess - Forget about hardening the security for a moment. Can you connect without doing all those steps?

Comment: No. Same situation - nothing happens after typing 'ssh working_name@working_device'

Comment: @MeirZeilig-Hess - It would seem then that you don't have port forwarding set up correctly.

Comment: Maybe. I didn't understand how to use the port-forward page in the link you put.

Comment: @MeirZeilig-Hess - I didn't put that in. I was quoting somebody else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41003/discussion-between-android-dev-and-meir-zeilig-hess).

Comment: OK, I managed to make it. The only one more thing I needed was to connect to the work server before connecting to the work computer. Thank you for all the help!