# ssh through vpn working randomly

Tags: ssh, vpn, remote-access

Sometimes I need to connect to my university workstation (Ubuntu 16.04) from wherever I happen to be at that time using my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04). To do so, I prepared the university workstation to accept ssh connections as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections).

However, I don't know why sometime I can connect normally but many other times I get the error that `ssh: Could not resolve hostname`. Any ideas why can this happen?