# Is it possible to run System Monitor for another machine?

Tags: system-monitor

Is it possible to run System Monitor on one machine but connected and displayed another Ubuntu machine?
For example I have a remote machine and want to see its RAM usage, CPUs etc.
Or may be something other tool, ...and how to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: And how to do it? :-)

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. I'd `ssh` into the remote machine and call `top`

Comment: ...related https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect via SSH and just type the same commands you would use on your local machine.

```
ssh remote_user@remote_host
```